# Is there any way to enable javascript in browser using java code?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

Is there any way to enable javascript code using java?
Suppose I am developing one web application on which I am using javascript or jquery.If client disable javascript from his browser then my whole javascript code is not working .I want if client  disable javascript from browser then he load my application at the loading time my javacode run and enable the javascript.
So please tell me if there is any process which can I do through java to enable javascript in browser.

thanks & regards,
shivam

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What would be the point of disabling JavaScript if the websites could re-enable it?

Comment: It should not be possible from security point of view.

Answer (score 1):

> So please tell me if there is any process which can I do through java to enable javascript in browser.

There isn't.

If the user has decided to disable Javascript, then there is no way to enable it.  And even if there was a way, you >>should not<< do it.  His browser, his choice.  Respect it!

The best you can do is detect that the user has disabled Javascript and  either  warn him / her that your site won't work properly, or redirect the browser to a non-javascript version of your site.